# interactive grep in javascript?

Tags: javascript, grep

I'm looking to make a page that would show about 20k lines and a textbox on top, and as I'm typing into textbox, it will restrict the list to ones containing the string I typed. I have no javascript background so I'm looking for a simple example that I can modify to get this working, any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a couple of tweaks to @Marc B's answer but it's still not very performant:

- Show/Hide items using a class
- Use match instead of indexOf

Here's the code for it: http://jsfiddle.net/gTBFN/3/

Comment: Wow, this is actually pretty much what I was looking for! It seems a bit slow for interactive use, so maybe I can figure out a way for this to trigger in Enter instead of key up

Answer (score 3):

For this to work, you'd have to wrap each line of the text in an appropriate container, so that you can hide/show individual lines.

e.g.

```
<div class="hideables">
    <div>line 1</div>
    <div>line 2</div>
    ...
</div>
```

With jquery, you could do something like

```
$('.hideables div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('yourstring') != -1) {
       $(this).show();
    } else {
       $(this).hide();
    }
});
```